# x-bar theory - the conjunction "and" connecting different elements

Tags: x-bar-theory, conjunctions

Normally, We use the conjunction "and" to connect two words, phrases, or clauses with the same grammatical functions and grammatical forms. But I wonder how to draw a tree if the conjunction "and" connect two different elements. For example, the sentence "He was tired and in a bad mood."

Answer (score 1):

In X-bar theory, “tired” is an adjectival phrase (adj becomes adj-bar becomes adj-double-bar) and “in a bad mood” is an adjectival phrase (prep+NP-double-bar becomes adj becomes adj-bar becomes adj-double-bar).